# Matrix Iterating: What is the function of this code?

Tags: matlab

It is part of the gauss seidel iteration method to solve matrices but I'm not sure what this piece of code does.    A matrix 'A' is predefined.

```
[columns,rows] = size(A);
L = zeros(size(A));
U = zeros(size(A));

for i = 1:columns
for j = 1:i
    L(i,j) = A(i,j);
end
for j = i+1:columns
    U(i,j) = A(i,j);
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That function simply finds the [lower and upper triangular portions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Description) of the matrix.  You're getting that "undefined" error because you have not defined `A` yet.  Define `A`, then run the code:

```
A = rand(6,6); % For example
% Rest of your code goes here....
```

`L` and `U` will contain the **l**ower and **u**pper portions of the matrix `A`.

**Minor Note:** You are using `size` wrong.  The first output parameter is the rows while the second output parameter is the columns.  Swap the variables:

```
[rows, columns] = size(A);
```

Comment: Thanks. How exactly does,say, L contain the Lower part of the matrix?

Comment: @Monty `L` iterates through all of the rows, but only capture from the first column up to diagonal element.  `U` does the same but for the column, we go from the diagonal element to the last column.  You can see it in the code.  BTW, if this has helped, consider accepting this answer to let every know you don't need more help on this issue. Good luck!